# Sum of elements in the nth set of the sequence of sets of squares $\{1\}$, $\{4,9\}$, $\{16,25,36\}$, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $S_n$ denote the sum of the elements in the $n^{th}$ set of the sequence of sets of squares: $\{1\}$, $\{4,9\}$, $\{16,25,36\}$, $\{49,64,81,100\}$,.... i.e. $S_1 = 1$, $S_2 = 13$, ... How do you find a formula for $S_n$?

*Note:* this is from Koshy, Elementary Number Theory 2nd Edition, problem set 1.3, ex 45.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours are
$$\{1^2\},\{2^2,3^2\},\{4^2,5^2,6^2\},\{7^2,8^2,9^2,{10}^2\},\cdots.$$

So, the first element of the $n$-th set will be $i^2$ such that
$$i=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=1+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}=\frac{n^2-n+2}{2}.$$

Hence, 
$$S_n=\sum_{k=(n^2-n+2)/2}^{((n^2-n+2)/2)+n-1}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^{((n^2-n+2)/2)+n-1}k^2-\sum_{k=1}^{((n^2-n+2)/2)-1}k^2.$$

Here, you can use
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p}k^2=\frac{p(p+1)(2p+1)}{6}.$$

Comment: I don't think that this is the problematic step...(but I may be wrong)

Comment: @chubakueno: I added a bit.

Comment: The last formula is not true, that one is just for the naturals.

Comment: @chubakueno: But they are natural numbers.

Comment: Someone flagged this answer, but l was adding some steps.

Comment: @chubakueno: Note that $(n^2-n+2)/2=1+(n(n-1)/2)$ is a natural number for $n\in\mathbb N.$

Comment: Could that be a typo? because $\sum_{k=1}^{p}k=\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$

Comment: Cheers mathlove, my solution was similar to what you did (just had to figure out what the first element of the nth set was then it was straight forward).

Comment: Yeah Mick, he made a typo :D should be $p(p+1)(2p+1)/6$

Comment: @Mick: Thank you for pointing it out. I edited it.

Comment: @liedora: I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: I was pointing the same error as Mick and liedora, sorry for not explaining myself appropriately. +1.

Comment: @chubakueno: I see. Never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you compute the sum of $n$ consecutive squares $\sum_{i=x}^y i^2$? Can you figure out a closed form for the first square in your groupings?

Comment: Yes I know the sum of first n squares, but I can't seem to work out what squares are in my groupings (i.e. the squares in the nth sequence)

Comment: I think it's easiest if you try to figure out the first term in each group. 1,2,4,7,11,... Try OEIS if you're really stumped

Comment: Thanks Frederick, got the solution out after figuring out what the first element of each set was! My solution from there is similar to what mathlove posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The last number squared in the $k$th group is the $k$th triangular number $t(k)=k(k+1)/2$. So the sum of squares in the $k$th group is obtained by using the sum of the first $n$ squares formula $s(n)=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ and computing $s(p(k))-s(p(k-1).$ This gives
$$\frac{k(3k^4+7k^2+2)}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you compute S1 being the sum of squares from 1 to (m-1) and S2 being the sum of squares from 1 to n and substract S1 from S2, you have the sum of squares from m to n and the formula is then simply

(m (-1 + (3 - 2 m) m) + n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n)) / 6

Answer (score 0):

Our task is to calculate $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x+i)^2$$
where $x=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$
The general formula for calculating the sum of $k$ consecutive squares is well-known to be
$$\mathcal{S}_k=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$
In terms of $\mathcal{S}_n$, $S_n$ is
\begin{align*}
S_n&=\mathcal{S}_{x+n-1}-\mathcal{S}_{x-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}[k(k+1)(2k+1)-r(r+1)(2r+1)]
\end{align*}
where $k=x+n-1=(n^2+n)/2$ and $r=x-1=(n^2-n)/2$